# Как агрегировать данные в колонку таблицы в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

База данных PostgreSQL.

```sql
-- Товары
CREATE TABLE products (
    id integer SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    comment_count integer,
    available_count integer
);

-- Комментарии к товарам
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id integer SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE CASCADE,
    count_comments integer
);

-- Остатки по складам
CREATE TABLE store_product (
    id integer SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    store_id integer REFERENCES stores ON DELETE CASCADE,
    product_id integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE CASCADE,
    quantity integer
);
```

Необходимо агрегировать данные в столбцы `products.comment_count` и `products.available_count` при каждом изменении полей во внешних таблицах (откуда берутся данные).

Для `products.comment_count` необходимо подсчитывать количество комментариев.

Для `products.available_count` необходимо подсчитывать сумму в полях `store_product.quantity`.

Comment: Для этого надо написать соответствующие триггера на таблицы comments и store_product которые добавят/вычтут значения из счетчиков на основе данных из изменяемой записи

Comment: @Mike, если триггер привязан только к определённой таблице, он не влияет на производительность в других частях чтения/записи данной базы данных?

Comment: нет. они влияет только на те операции на которые он назначен (а это обычно изменение) только той таблицы на которой он создан

Comment: @Mike, я могу повесить триггер только на определённую или несколько колонок? Если Да, то повлияет ли это на производительность при изменении других столбцов таблицы, если отслеживаемая не изменяется?